# Pass special character to script including single-quote, double-quote etc

Tags: bash, special-characters

is it possible to pass a word with special characters to a script?
Almost every special character is possible, so also single-quotes, double-quotes and so on.

I would like to call my script like so for example:

```
./my_script.sh my'"sp%ecial'word
```

Hoewever that doesn't work.

for now I added `read -rp "please enter string" a`

This seems to work fine, but I don't want to prompt for that string, I would rather like to hand it over as an argument.

The only special character which my string does not contain is a space. Maybe this helps?

Thanks!

Comment: Spend some time with [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the manual -- you need to wrap the word in single quotes, except that literal single quotes cannot be embedded in a single quoted string: `./my_script.sh 'my'\''"sp%ecial'\''word'` -- then, in the script, make sure that `"$1"` is quoted everywhere you use it.

Comment: @Manuel : You can escape all characters which have special meaning to bash, by prefixing them with a backslash `\\`.